# InfoPath offline mode for retrieving database connection

Tags: infopath, offline

I've some doubt in infopath 2007.

I want to use infopath in offline mode. but in the template I have a lookup column which needs to be retrieved from external database (sharepoint list).

So how do I open that form in offline mode(No network access) and retrieve those values.

I have tried some other ways but no result. can u help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your plan will not work. 
First, when you open an infopath form, the template must be either accessible or cached.
For the form template to be accessible, an internet connection and connection to the server must be present. To check what url the user needs access to, you can open the form that you are sending with notepad and find the "mso-infoPathSolution" node. Find the href field in that, that value is the url that must be accessible to the user. If it is behind a firewall, or a local address, they will not be able to access the template.

Another road block is if you have data connections. A copy of the data connections can only be cached if the form has been opened on that machine before. If the user will not have access to the data connections because of security, the same issue is present as the first issue.

If the user will have access to the data connections, you could send them the template (.xsn) file. They can create a new form off of the template, and the data connections will be cached.

Otherwise you may have to host your infopath on sharepoint and send them a link to the form from there. ([server]/_layouts/formserver.aspx?XsnLocation=[xsn template path])

Hope this helps, InfoPath is not very good at being sent places.

Answer (score 0):

u can save a local copy of the data connection file. When creating a new data connection there you will find a check box stating -Store a local copy. Just check it and save the data connection. I guess it will solve ur issue.

Comment: Hi, I checked that check box (store a local copy of template). even i'm not able to resolve. actually what i'm doing is sending this infopath form to external user through mail for filling out this form. so at user point of view he is not able to view form because of server connecting.. can u help me out ?